# How to get max directory by its name from HDFS?

Tags: linux, hdfs

The below is the directory structure of my HDFS as per hadoop 2.6.0

```
/user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2016-12-27/outputfile.txt
/user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2016-12-28/outputfile.txt
/user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2016-12-29/outputfile.txt
..
```

I would like to get the max output directory by its name from a parent HDFS directory

```
OUTPUT_HDFS_DIR=/user/cloudera/output_files
latest_output_dir= hdfs dfs -ls -d $OUTPUT_HDFS_DIR/* | sort -n | tail -1

echo $latest_output_dir// This line is printing

latest_date_dir=$(basename "$latest_output_dir")
echo $latest_date_dir//This line is not printin. Getting a empty space.
```

Output of above shell script

```
[cloudera@client09 scripts]$ bash latest_dir.sh
drwxrwx---   - cloudera cloudera          0 2017-04-19 13:35 /user/cloudera/output_files/file_date_2016-12-29
```

I am expecting  $latest_date_dir to be printed as **file_date_2016-12-29**,but it is  not displaying that.

Could someone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line:

```
latest_output_dir= hdfs dfs -ls -d $OUTPUT_HDFS_DIR/* | sort -n | tail -1
```

to:

```
latest_output_dir=`hdfs dfs -ls -d $OUTPUT_HDFS_DIR/* | sort -n | tail -1`
```

**Explanation**: Your command will be executed but the output wont be assigned to the variable. The change which I am suggesting will do the missing part (assign it to the variable).